# Subgroups in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a report that will list sales data broken down into subgroups. The hierarchy I'm working with is State > Store > Sales Agent. I'd like to create something similar to this:

```
[State Name]
    [Net Sales]   [Net Revenue]
[Store Name]
    [Net Sales]   [Net Revenue]
[Sales Agent]
    [Net Sales]   [Net Revenue]
```

I was able to implement this in Business Objects, but I'm having trouble creating the same thing in Crystal Reports. I've tried to create nested groups, but they come out looking like this:

```
[State Name]
[Store Name]
[Sales Agent]
    [Net Sales]   [Net Revenue]
```

Is there a way to display data for all three subgroups within the same report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Crystal Reports using Summary objects, and putting them in the group header or footer sections.  Something like this:

```
[State Name]      [Sum of Net Revenue]
[Store Name]      [Sum of Net Revenue]
[Sales Agent]     [Sum of Net Revenue]
    [Net Sales]   [Net Revenue]
```

This actually creates 3 different summary objects, one for each group, which will contain the sum of net revenue for all Sales Agents in that group.

Once you've done that, you should be able to add any other summaries (or use a different operation if you like, such as average) to your sections.

Answer (score 0):

@DixieFlatline
To some extent you have done correctly. Follow below steps you would be able to see summary.

1. Create 3 groups (you have done already)
2. Now place `net sales` and `net revenue` in detail and right click and got to insert summary and create summary for all 3 groups.
3. Go to group1 and create a sub section for group 1 using option `insert a section below` now place group 1 summary there, In the same way acheive all summaries.

Let me know if you still face issues.